# How do I attach some entity fields (or widgets?) to a form?

Tags: 7, entities

I am providing a form to a user to create a product.  I want to provide a few fields from a product type, along with some normal Form API input.  Example, I only want them to specify the price and SKU.  I want the submit handler to take care of creating the title name and any other fields.  In this case, a product lives as product entities and as product display nodes.  I want to present my user a single form to create and manage products.

I looks like I should be able to do this with the Field API, but I just see how to attached all fields from an entity.  I just want to attach a few.

Am I able to do this with the Field API?

EDIT TO ADD MORE INFO:

For example, when a user creates a new product, they will enter a 6 digit SKU.  Each product will have that SKU, with another 3 digits appended, specifying a category.  I want the user to simply enter the base SKU, like ABCDEF, select category Y and Z, and the submit handler creates the products with the correct SKUs, like ABCDEF-0001, ABCDEF-0002, and creates the node display.  There are also specific fields of the product type, so I need the user to populate the fields for these products, using the WYSIWYG filter they would otherwise use on the product create form.

Comment: I think I want the widget of the field, and the ability to validate and collect the field values on submit.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you can certainly use [field_attach_form](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.attach.inc/function/field_attach_form/7). Take a look at the `$options` argument that is explained in more detail in the [_field_invoke](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.attach.inc/function/_field_invoke/7) documentation. For more information you can also have a look at this issue: https://drupal.org/node/1825844

You can include any field of any bundle into any form using this approach:

```
field_attach_form('node', $entity, $form, $form_state, NULL, array(
  'field_name' => 'field_sku',
));
```

When I last used this approach I remember having passed a copy of the original form into field_attach_form() in order to prevent my original form from being modified to much. Then I have copied only field element into my original form:

```
$form_tmp = $form;
field_attach_form('node', $entity, $form_tmp, $form_state, NULL, array(
  'field_name' => 'field_sku'
));
$form['field_sku'] = $form_tmp['field_sku'];
```

Just look at the mentioned functions to see what they do. I'm not sure if this last part is needed.

And one more link to explore:

- https://api.drupal.org/comment/49363#comment-49363

Comment: I can add multiple fields?

Comment: Yes, just call field_attach_form() several time.

Comment: Just wanted to say thanks for this answer! Helped me immensely!

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for [Inline Entity Form](https://drupal.org/project/inline_entity_form) module

> Provides a widget for inline management (**creation, modification,
>   removal**) of referenced entities. The primary use case is the parent ->
>   children one (product display -> products, order -> line items, etc.),
>   where the child entities are never managed outside the parent form.
>   Existing entities can also be referenced.

Comment: I need to present certain fields from the product display, and certain fields from the products, with their WYSIWYG filters.  I don't think this module offers that.